# How to sort numerically but read_csv with dtype=object?

Tags: python, pandas

Given this much simplified test.csv file:

```
wrong
8
7
6
3
1
2
4
5
9
10
```

and this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype=object)
counts=data['wrong'].value_counts(dropna=False)
counts_converted=counts.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

print counts_converted.sort_index()
```

produces the following output:

```
1     1
10    1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
dtype: int64
```

Why does the last print statement not sort the index 1-10?

I have to force the dtype to object when the csv file is read to overcome some issues with detecting mixed character, date, and numeric formats in columns, so removing that statement isn't going to work for me.

I thought that I could just convert the series back to numeric, but it doesn't seem to work.

Editing question since commenting was not allowing me to use the Enter key without posting the comment... [Ahh, found many long rants about this feature. Shift-Enter works.]

@EdChum suggested solution works for simplified case, but does not work with production data. Consider a slightly less simple data file:

```
wrong,right
8,a
7,b
6,c
3,d
1,
2,f
4,g
5,h
9,i
10,j
,k
11,l
```

The empty value on the second to last line causes an error "cannot convert float NaN to integer."

I have many NaNs (all empty) that need to be kept and counted in the value_counts.

Other empty cells seem to turn up as very large negative numbers (i.e. -5226413792388707240) upon casting to int64.

Apologies in advance for any obtuseness on my part! Thanks for the help.

Comment: You've read the values in as `object` this makes the values `str` in effect, you call `value_counts` which then sets the index to your values, you then called `convert_objects` but this has no effect as it's your index that needs converting

Answer (score 1):

Adding an `astype` after reading makes it sort properly.

You mention you have to sort out some mixed characters and dates and stuff, do that before the `astype` and everything should be fine.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/home/mikael/test.csv', dtype=object)

# Sanitize your data here

data['wrong'] = data['wrong'].astype(int)
counts=data['wrong'].value_counts(dropna=False)
counts_converted=counts.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

print counts_converted.sort_index()

1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you called `value_counts` on the df before any type conversion, so your `value_counts` index is still `object` dtype which is a `str`:

```
In [59]:

t="""wrong
8
7
6
3
1
2
4
5
9
10"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), dtype=object)
counts=df['wrong'].value_counts(dropna=False)
counts.index
Out[59]:
Index(['4', '6', '2', '9', '3', '10', '5', '1', '8', '7'], dtype='object')
```

Calling `convert_objects` converts data not the index.

If you cast your index type to `np.int64` then it sorts correctly:

```
counts.index = counts.index.astype(np.int64)
counts.sort_index()
Out[74]:
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
dtype: int64
```